# How Do I Display Image Slider Twice in One Page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/09750p95/12/

I Am Using Wordpress.

I Am Creating a Custom Theme.

I Am Doing a Pokemon Website.

I Want A 150 Pokemon Slider in Top Left DIV AND Bottom Right DIV.

I Have .PNG Files for All 150 Pokemon.

I Have < img > tags for All 150 Pokemon saved in "slider.php".

"slider.php"

www.GoHatchMyEgg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/slider.php

**SLIDER.PHP**

```
<div id="Slider">
<img id="1" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/001.png" />
<img id="2" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/002.png" />
<img id="3" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/003.png" />
<img id="4" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/004.png" />
<img id="5" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/005.png" />
<img id="6" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/006.png" />
<img id="7" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/007.png" />
<img id="8" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/008.png" />
<img id="9" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/009.png" />
<img id="10" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/010.png" />
<img id="11" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/011.png" />
<img id="12" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/012.png" />
<img id="13" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/013.png" />
<img id="14" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/014.png" />
<img id="15" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/015.png" />
<img id="16" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/016.png" />
<img id="17" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/017.png" />
<img id="18" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/018.png" />
<img id="19" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/019.png" />
<img id="20" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/020.png" />
<img id="21" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/021.png" />
<img id="22" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/022.png" />
<img id="23" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/023.png" />
<img id="24" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/024.png" />
<img id="25" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/025.png" />
<img id="26" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/026.png" />
<img id="27" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/027.png" />
<img id="28" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/028.png" />
<img id="29" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/029.png" />
<img id="30" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/030.png" />
<img id="31" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/031.png" />
<img id="32" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/032.png" />
<img id="33" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/033.png" />
<img id="34" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/034.png" />
<img id="35" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/035.png" />
<img id="36" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/036.png" />
<img id="37" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/037.png" />
<img id="38" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/038.png" />
<img id="39" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/039.png" />
<img id="40" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/040.png" />
<img id="41" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/041.png" />
<img id="42" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/042.png" />
<img id="43" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/043.png" />
<img id="44" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/044.png" />
<img id="45" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/045.png" />
<img id="46" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/046.png" />
<img id="47" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/047.png" />
<img id="48" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/048.png" />
<img id="49" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/049.png" />
<img id="50" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/050.png" />
<img id="51" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/051.png" />
<img id="52" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/052.png" />
<img id="53" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/053.png" />
<img id="54" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/054.png" />
<img id="55" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/055.png" />
<img id="56" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/056.png" />
<img id="57" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/057.png" />
<img id="58" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/058.png" />
<img id="59" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/059.png" />
<img id="60" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/060.png" />
<img id="61" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/061.png" />
<img id="62" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/062.png" />
<img id="63" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/063.png" />
<img id="64" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/064.png" />
<img id="65" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/065.png" />
<img id="66" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/066.png" />
<img id="67" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/067.png" />
<img id="68" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/068.png" />
<img id="69" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/069.png" />
<img id="70" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/070.png" />
<img id="71" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/071.png" />
<img id="72" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/072.png" />
<img id="73" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/073.png" />
<img id="74" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/074.png" />
<img id="75" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/075.png" />
<img id="76" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/076.png" />
<img id="77" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/077.png" />
<img id="78" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/078.png" />
<img id="79" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/079.png" />
<img id="80" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/080.png" />
<img id="81" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/081.png" />
<img id="82" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/082.png" />
<img id="83" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/083.png" />
<img id="84" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/084.png" />
<img id="85" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/085.png" />
<img id="86" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/086.png" />
<img id="87" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/087.png" />
<img id="88" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/088.png" />
<img id="89" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/089.png" />
<img id="90" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/090.png" />
<img id="91" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/091.png" />
<img id="92" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/092.png" />
<img id="93" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/093.png" />
<img id="94" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/094.png" />
<img id="95" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/095.png" />
<img id="96" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/096.png" />
<img id="97" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/097.png" />
<img id="98" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/098.png" />
<img id="99" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/099.png" />
<img id="100" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/1.png" />
<img id="101" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/101.png" />
<img id="102" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/102.png" />
<img id="103" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/103.png" />
<img id="104" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/104.png" />
<img id="105" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/105.png" />
<img id="106" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/106.png" />
<img id="107" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/107.png" />
<img id="108" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/108.png" />
<img id="109" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/109.png" />
<img id="110" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/110.png" />
<img id="111" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/111.png" />
<img id="112" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/112.png" />
<img id="113" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/113.png" />
<img id="114" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/114.png" />
<img id="115" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/115.png" />
<img id="116" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/116.png" />
<img id="117" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/117.png" />
<img id="118" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/118.png" />
<img id="119" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/119.png" />
<img id="120" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/120.png" />
<img id="121" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/121.png" />
<img id="122" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/122.png" />
<img id="123" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/123.png" />
<img id="124" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/124.png" />
<img id="125" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/125.png" />
<img id="126" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/126.png" />
<img id="127" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/127.png" />
<img id="128" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/128.png" />
<img id="129" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/129.png" />
<img id="130" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/130.png" />
<img id="131" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/131.png" />
<img id="132" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/132.png" />
<img id="133" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/133.png" />
<img id="134" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/134.png" />
<img id="135" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/135.png" />
<img id="136" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/136.png" />
<img id="137" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/137.png" />
<img id="138" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/138.png" />
<img id="139" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/139.png" />
<img id="140" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/140.png" />
<img id="141" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/141.png" />
<img id="142" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/142.png" />
<img id="143" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/143.png" />
<img id="144" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/144.png" />
<img id="145" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/145.png" />
<img id="146" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/146.png" />
<img id="147" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/147.png" />
<img id="148" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/148.png" />
<img id="149" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/149.png" />
<img id="150" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/150.png" />
</div>
```

I Was Also Successful at Turning All 150 Pokemon .PNG Files into A Pokemon Slideshow.

Here is The JSFiddle

**POKEMON SLIDER**

http://jsfiddle.net/1cyr8w0c/6/

Here is The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//$('#Slider #1').show({right:'0'}, 500);
$('#Slider #1').show('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
$('#Slider #1').delay(5500).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},500);

var sliderTotalImg = $('#Slider img').size();    
var counterIndex = 2;
var slidecount=4;

setInterval(function () {

    //$('#Slider #' + counterIndex).show({right:'0'}, 500);
    $('#Slider #' + counterIndex).show('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
    $('#Slider #' + counterIndex).delay(5500).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},500);

    if(counterIndex==slidecount){
counterIndex=1;

}else{
counterIndex++;
}
},6500);});
```

I want THAT Slider to Display and Show TWICE in The FIRST JSFiddle.

1x in The Top Left DIV Box (PC SLIDER)

and

1x in The Bottom Right DIV Box. (MOBILE SLIDER)

How do I do this?

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

I tried < ?php include ?> TWICE.

```
<div id="TopLeft">

<div id="TopLeftTitle">
<center><strong>PC<br>SLIDER</strong></center>
</div>
<div id="SliderContainer">
<div id="Slider"><center>
<br>I Want
<br>Pokemon Slider
<br>Here</center><?php include 'http://www.GoHatchMyEgg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/slider.php';?></div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="BottomRight">

<div id="BottomRightTitle">
<center><strong>PC<br>SLIDER</strong></center>
</div>
<div id="SliderContainer">
<div id="Slider"><center>
<br>I Want
<br>Pokemon Slider
<br>Here</center><?php include 'http://www.GoHatchMyEgg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/slider.php';?></div>
</div>
</div>
```

And THEN,

I tried AJAX Get HTML(Data) Method TWICE.

Both methods only worked once for 1 DIV Box.

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

How do I get The Pokemon Slider to Display and Work in Top Left DIV and Bottom Right DIV of The FIRST JSFiddle.?

Comment: do you know what is an array? if you don't then go and search it. learn about array. then get your all images and save it in one array. then you have an access to them more than 1 time.

Comment: But how do I turn an image array into an image slider?